# UML Sequence Diagrams

Tags: eclipse, uml, modeling

I am having some problems modeling SD with Eclipse Papyrus, not because of the tool (which is actually very well made), but, I guess, because of a wrong understanding I have of the OMG spec.

Consider this simple example:

I have a model with a class `ClassA` containing two instances of two different classes `(say bObj:ClassB and cObj:ClassC)`.
`ClassA` provides an Operation (i.e. classAOperation(int param)) related to a Behavior specified by means of a SequenceDiagram.

Now the behavior consists of invoking an Operation of bObj:ClassB (**i.e**. classBOperation(int param)) and an Operation of `cObj:ClassC` (i.e. classCOperation(int param)).

I am wondering how to model, this very simple behavior, via SD.
The question is basically related to LifeLine.

According to the OMG spec. a Lifeline can only represent (Represents attribute) a ConnectableElement, which in my case are two and correspond to the `ClassA` Properties realizing the composition to a `ClassB` and a `ClassC` instance `(bObj and cObj)`.

The Problem is, I also need to have a reference to the container of these connectable elements, that is to say the `ClassA` instance which is actually performing such emergent behavior. It is that instance which sends messages (related to the operation call) o to the `bObj:ClassB` and `cObj:ClassC` lifelines.
Also as this behavior corresponds to the `ClassA:classAOperation(int param)` invocation I also need to represents by means of a formal gate the classAOperation(int param) message. But again, as I can't mode the container Lifeline I can't see to which attach the classAOperation(int param) message end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to refer to the self instance

In fact UML spec 2.5b1 page 607, about a Lifeline is said.
If the name is the keyword self, then the Lifeline represents the object of the classifier that encloses the Interaction that owns the Lifeline. Ports of the encloser may be shown separately even when self is included.

[image]

See 
http://lowcoupling.com/post/47844944042/uml-sequence-diagrams

for a complete example

Answer (score -1):

I think, in sequence diagram you need show sequence of calls and no more. I think, is no important about connectable elements, reference to the container etc. It is just shows chain of calls between objects. I can call sequence diagram: messaging diagram.

[image: sequence diagram]

Comment: According to the UML specification a Sequence Diagram Lifeline shall always refer to a Connectable Element.

Comment: Here is another forum in which I posted the same question. The thing is getting interesting there. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/999676/#msg_999676

Comment: The problem with your model is that it can't be defined within the ClassA Classifier. I should define a fake User class owning an instance of ClassA and there define the SD a similar to the one you propose in which the User lifeline is not present (because there wouldn't be a connectable element for it) and the ClassA lifeline (referret to the User.aObject attribute) receives the classAOperation as a message from a formal gate. However defining a ClassA behavior outside of the ClassA Classifier is quite counterintuitive. I hope there is another way for that